# Why Is the West providing technology to India?

Tags: technology

Previously, we have seen that Europeans and Americans provided various technologies (high-speed rail<sup>[1]</sup>, aerospace<sup>[2]</sup><sup>[3]</sup>, microprocessor<sup>[4]</sup>, etc.) to China to earn instantaneous money. Later what happened was, China did its own research on those techs, improved them and became a giant vendor.

Apparently, the same is being repeated in case of India. The USA and EU is giving India missile tech<sup>[5]</sup>, nuclear tech<sup>[6]</sup>, aircraft carrier tech<sup>[7]</sup>, fighter jet tech<sup>[8]</sup>, and so on. India is also making 100% sure that they obtain those techs by enforcing a so-called policy named: "Make in India"<sup>[9]</sup>.

My question is, Why Is the West providing technology to India even though there is an imminent danger to the West of India becoming a 2nd giant vendor?

**References**

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-speed_rail_in_China#Acquisition_of_foreign_technology
2. https://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/defense/2017-06-20/new-chinese-fighters-tap-russian-us-technology
3. https://www.cnbc.com/2017/09/18/rolls-royce-chairman-ian-davis-on-chinese-jet-engines-singapore-summit.html
4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loongson#MIPS_patent_issues
5. http://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-l-t-mbda-idUKKBN15S0XG
6. http://www.firstpost.com/india/india-us-nuclear-deal-all-you-need-to-know-about-the-landmark-agreement-3596209.html
7. http://www.news18.com/news/world/us-to-provide-emals-technology-to-india-for-aircraft-carriers-1550359.html
8. https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/defence/us-updates-jet-engine-technology-transfer-policy-with-india/articleshow/50131574.cms
9. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_in_India

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is fundamentally a political question.

Comment: Because if there was a market for ropes to hang capitalists, capitalists would produce them?

Answer (score 0):

I may hazard a small guess to this. India has a very young workforce in comparison to its Asian counterparts (China and Japan). We especially see this in the field of software design where it has an even lower median age of labour than USA. As we know the West gains a lot from brain drain and stands to gain even more from young innovative minds that India produces, we can assume this access to new technology will let India produce even more bright minds.

As for India becoming a large vendor. We can see China will be facing extreme labour shortages soon due to it's high aged labour force and extreme brain drain. This in turn has China to be predicted to fall as a large vendor in the global market (Or at least possible). If it does India can take its place, easing the instability of the market, and if it doesn't we have a new youth force with amazing work ethic gain from.

Also from an Economic view more vendors in the market is decentralizing, which can be seen as good or bad depending.

Hope this had something to gain.

Comment: Reading this, I am getting a feeling that the West is so much benevolent to those countries that colonialism sounds like a fairy tale.

Comment: Well not entirely true as we will ultimately gain, by no means was I implying we are selfless. You must realise we are in a new age and how we colonize has changed. Instead of taking a country's lands, it is now their minds (the labour force). Also inturn this will Westernize the youth's minds, making them adapt to our way of thought for integration purposes. I hope this clarifies that I was not saying the West is benevolent (nor am I saying they are malevolent).

Comment: As I said, this is 2nd China in the making. The result would be the losing of western lead in the area of sci-tech. China has world's 2nd largest R&D expenditure. India is probably in the top 10.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question using principles of market competition, I would do so to avoid delving into the geopolitical ramifications of technology transfer, since it has no direct relation to pure economics.

My competitors's enemy is not a friend, but a considerable force so as to help me keep my competitor busy and force him to use his resources to compete. Here, US and other western nations, say NATO are trying to use India as a force to compete directly with China. Given the pathetic infrastructure and colonial laws of Indian Union, it is logical that no western nation sees India as a real rival to China. But then it is good to have China compete, this will ensure two things.

$1)$ Force China to allocate a considerable amount of its resources to sectors which it wouldn't have had (had there been no purported Indian threat)

$2)$ If Chinese and Indian manufacturers flood the market with their goods, then who gets the positive end result, the consumers but obviously.

An important point to note is that with the given bureaucracy in India being near to 100% corrupt (its a fact), and with defence lobby infiltrated by foreign vendors; has resulted in the Indian indigenous defence organizations to stagnate. Also, the technology transfer is of systems and methodologies which are not going to have a reverse effect on the West.

For instance, Russia has literally help India to build two SLBM capable nuclear powered submarines, and leased other two nuclear submarines to India. Now that is something west is not up to. What west is doing instead is supplying not so lethal toys, like Submarine hunter planes. These cannot be used on a mass scale, say for invasion of Pakistan or liberation of Tibet.

This is very different to what china has done, but that is irrelevant to what you asked.

Comment: I have a few questions about some of the statements you made.  (1) "bureaucracy in India being near to 100% corrupt (its a fact)" - do you have any citations for this? (2) "logical that no Western nation sees India as a real rival to China" - I did not understand what you mean - rival in what sense/market?

Answer (score -1):

1) "The West" is comprised of quite a number of different countries. Among other things, almost none of them have the words "United" or "States" in their names.

2) Free trade logic is, by definition, not the main guiding logic when a sector is defined as a strategic sector.

3) Perhaps Western firms should be banned from exporting to any non-Western country? Would that be good for Western countries?

4) When "Made in India" becomes a quality stamp for anything other than curry, maybe more people will worry more about India becoming a 2nd (or 7th/8th at best, as it were) vendor.